# WP_Query последующая обработка результатов

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице вывожу произвольные посты циклом WP_Query.
Необходимо получить все посты с определенными параметрами, а уже потом выполнить подсчет через `$query->found_posts;`
Но тут особенность, надо посчитать:
сколько постов с `'comment_status' => 'open'`
сколько с `'comment_status' => 'closed'`.

А для вывода сами постов еще раз результат первого запроса отфильтровать и вывести только, например, с `'comment_status' => 'open'`.

Это можно сделать в рамках одного цикла? Конечно, можно по простому наплодить циклов, но так себе решение.

```
<div class="cases_counts">

    <?php 

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

        // Запрос к БД
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'post_type' => 'cases',
            'author' => $current_user_id,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );


    ?>



    <div class="cases_count">Открытые: <?php echo $query->found_posts; ?></div>
    <div class="cases_count">Закрытые: </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">

<!-- тут боковая панель -->

</div>
<div class="content">



    <div class="case_list">
        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                if ( 'open' == $post->comment_status ) { // если комментарии открыты
                echo $query->found_posts;
                    echo '<div class="case_item">
                                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">
                                    <span class="case_item_title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>
                                    <span class="case_item_id">Идентификатор: ' . get_the_ID() . '</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $item = '<div class="nocases">Обращений нет.</div>';
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [rewind_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/rewind_posts). Постройте первый цикл как обычно, потом rewind и снова цикл. Всё будет в памяти, никаких лишних обращений к базе.

Выглядеть код должен примерно так:

```
<div class="cases_counts">
    <?php
    global $post;

    $current_user    = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

    // Запрос к БД
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_type'      => 'cases',
        'author'         => $current_user_id,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $open   = 0;
    $closed = 0;
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $check = ( 'open' === $post->comment_status );
            if ( $check ) {
                $open ++;
            } else {
                $closed ++;
            }
        }
    }
    rewind_posts();
    ?>

    <div class="cases_count">Открытые: <?php echo $open; ?></div>
    <div class="cases_count">Закрытые: <?php echo $closed; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <!-- тут боковая панель -->
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="case_list">
        <?php
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                if ( 'open' === $post->comment_status ) { // если комментарии открыты
                    echo '<div class="case_item">
                                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">
                                    <span class="case_item_title">' . get_the_title() . '</span>
                                    <span class="case_item_id">Идентификатор: ' . get_the_ID() . '</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $item = '<div class="nocases">Обращений нет.</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: т.е. запустить цикл wp_query со всеми нужными аргументами, но не запускать `if( have_posts() ){ while( have_posts()){ the_post();`. После выполнить rewind_posts. После снова весь цикл wp_query со всеми аргументами+дополнительными или только с дополнительными?

Comment: Я добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: у Камы примерно такой же пример. Только в том то и вопрос, сначала ведь цикл должен собрать посты без параметра comment_status, а уже полученную выборку прогнать по данному параметру.

Comment: Во втором цикле проверяйте программно comment_status и пропускайте ненужные посты.

Comment: Программно это как, простите за глупый вопрос? Через `if comments_open()` ?

Comment: через `$post->comment_status`

Comment: не затруднит показать кодом?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80191/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-aaron).

Comment: тут неприятный момент с условием в последнем цикле. Если посты есть, но они все с закрытыми комментариями, то выводится пустота, если пытаюсь добавить условие else, то результат этого условия повторяется то количество раз, сколько постов нашлось в целом циклом.